# perldoc/POD - don't add extra line in paragraph

Tags: perl, documentation

I'm trying to write some POD documentation and use perldoc to display it.  My goal is to get the format to look like this:

```
REQUIRED ARGUMENTS
    argument1
        Description of the first argument. 

    argmuent2
        Description of the second argument.
```

Where "REQUIRED ARGUMENTS" is a bold header and "argument1" and "argument2" are italicized.

But I am not able to figure out how to get that specific indentation.

I've tried this:

```
=head1 REQUIRED ARGUMENTS

I<argument1>
Description of the first argument.

I<argument2>
Description of the second argument.
```

which produces the following (the bold header and the italics are correctly displayed, but the run-on of the descriptions is not desired):

```
REQUIRED ARGUMENTS
    argument1 Description of the first argument.

    argument2 Description of the second argument.
```

And I've tried:

```
=head1 REQUIRED ARGUMENTS

I<argument1>

Description of the first argument.

I<argument2>

Description of the second argument.
```

Which produces the following (again the bold and italics are good, but now there is an extra line between the argument and the description):

```
REQUIRED ARGUMENTS
    argument1

    Description of the first argument.

    argument2

    Description of the second argument.
```

And amongst other things which have also not succeeded, I've tried this:

```
=head1 REQUIRED ARGUMENTS

I<argument1>

=over 4

Description of the first argument.

=back
```

With the following result:

```
REQUIRED ARGUMENTS
    argument1

        Description of the first argument.
```

Comment: What about `=head2 I<foo>`?

Comment: Note that your second example doesn't work because POD is a paragraph-based format. Newlines are collapsed, double-newlines separate paragraphs and directives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use items for the arguments:

```
=head1 REQUIRED ARGUMENTS

=over 4

=item I<argument1>

Description of the first argument.

=item I<argument2>

Description of the second argument.

=back

=cut
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept this answer as soon as the time limit allows me to.  I happened to find the same solution by looking at perldoc's own POD :)